# Maven dependency command not working

Tags: maven

I can run mvn clean compile and mvn install from command prompt but mvn dependency: tree doesn't work. I get:

Invalid task 'dependency': you must specify a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId : pluginVersion: goal.

Also for mvn eclipse : eclipse , I get
Invalid task 'eclipse' :blah

Am I missing any configuration here?
Thanks.

Comment: no space between `dependency:` and the goal `tree` which means `dependency:tree`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is

```
mvn dependency:tree
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

The part before the colon indicates the maven plugin, the part after the colon is the goal within the plugin that should be invoked. There must not be a space between the plugin name, the colon and the goal so that maven recognizes it as one argument

```
mvn <plugin>:<goal>
```

If you put a space there, maven thinks that each is is a separate argument and would e.g. try to run a goal "dependency" and another goal "tree".

Default lifecycle names (clean, install, etc.) are built-in and not part of plugins - therefore they work as they are without the ":" notation.